# java how to parse date format?

Tags: java, date

In java, how to write this date format?

```
Dec 17 2011 07:37:55:000PM
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M W yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"); // failed
```

I tried this format, it doesn't work.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need to expand your Month format to 3 M's and the days char is d not W.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa");
                      ^^^ ^^
```

Check here for more information on date formats http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html